# Javascript Success and Failure Callback both called(Do I need to add "return" after each callback)

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events

Playing around with the Cordova/Jasmine test framework has pointed out that my success and failure callbacks are both getting fired.

To fix this I added a return statements after each call back. Is this the best way to do it?

```
Connect : function(macAddress,success,failure) {
    if(!this.IsEnabled()){
        failure("Bluetooth Not Enabled");
        return;
    }

    this.CordovaBTObject.connect(
        macAddress,
        function(){
            success();
            return;
        },
        function(){
            failure("Could not connect to BT device");
            return;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you try walking through your code? Assuming you are using an emulator for this, possibly logging when you call, has always helped me find problems that turned out to be relatively simple

Comment: Yes, I have actually walked through the code. I am redoing the Cordova Bluetooth plugin with the aim of adding unit tests and separating the UI from it. To do this I am injecting the Cordova-Bluetooth-Plugin-Object making it much easier to test. What I am finding is that Jasmine is running multiple tests when I click on this particular test. (Feels like the tear-down bit is not happening before the next test.)

Comment: The `return` statements in your success and failure handlers you show in your code are completely optional and do not change the operation at all.

Comment: @BertusKruger then you have your answer, can you show the rest of your code? specifically however you are booting and testing the js

Comment: Thanks @konkked ... It was me teardown bit of my tests that did not fully clear the mocked/Cordova object I injected. Once I fixed it all started working.